# Adding logging quickly by annotations (like lombok for getters/setters) - is there any solutions available?

Tags: java, logging, annotations

Is there such a solution to facilitate tedious `logger.debug("bla-bla")` for my methods?

Specifically, is it posssible to automatically generate code like this:

```
if(logger.LEVEL == Level.DEBUG) {
   logger.debug("Entering method f(x,y) with arguments given x = " + xArg + ", y = " + yArg);
}
```

Lombok does not do this, please correct me if I miread its docs.

Comment: depending on your needs, you may try with aop

Answer (score 2):

```
@Log
public class LogExample {
  
  public static void main(String... args) {
    log.severe("Something's wrong here");
  }
}

@Slf4j
public class LogExampleOther {
  
  public static void main(String... args) {
    log.error("Something else is wrong here");
  }
}

@CommonsLog(topic="CounterLog")
public class LogExampleCategory {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    log.error("Calling the 'CounterLog' with a message");
  }
}
```

You could check Lombok 
 https://projectlombok.org/features/log

Comment: Looks like the requirement is one step ahead of this. In addition to have the "log" variable defined we also want the log.debug() call to be added before/around the method.